# Fetch data from a List and display in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I create a small `ASP.NET CORE MVC` which fetch User from ActiveDirectory. RIght now I need to display these data in View but I dont know how.

```
 public string VratiKorisnike()
        {
            List<Korisnik> lstuser = new List<Korisnik>();
            string sDomainName = "stesthu";
            string DomainPath = "LDAP://" + sDomainName;

            DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
            DirectorySearcher dssearch = new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://" + rootDSE);
            dssearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
            dssearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Ime");
            dssearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Prezime");
            dssearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("LoginName");
            dssearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Status");
            dssearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("AccountExpired");
            dssearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("PassNevExp");
            dssearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("DomenskaGrupa");
            dssearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Email");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Ime");
            dt.Columns.Add("Prezime");
            dt.Columns.Add("LoginName");
            dt.Columns.Add("Status");
            dt.Columns.Add("AccountExpired");
            dt.Columns.Add("PassNevExp");
            dt.Columns.Add("DomenskaGrupa");
            dt.Columns.Add("Email");

            SearchResult sresult = dssearch.FindOne();
            //int i = 0;

            SearchResultCollection resultCol = dssearch.FindAll();

            if (resultCol != null)
            {
                int counter;
                for (counter = 0; resultCol.Count < 0; counter++)
                {
                    //string UserNameEmail;

                    if (resultCol.PropertiesLoaded.Contains("Ime") || resultCol.PropertiesLoaded.Contains("Prezime"))
                    {
                        //List<Korisnik> korisnik = new List<Korisnik>();
                        Korisnik korisnik = new Korisnik();

                        var Ime = sresult.Properties["Ime"][0].ToString();
                        var Prezime = sresult.Properties["Prezime"][0].ToString();
                        var LoginName = sresult.Properties["LoginName"][0].ToString();
                        var Status = sresult.Properties["Status"][0].ToString();
                        var AccountExpired = sresult.Properties["AccountExpired"][0].ToString();
                        var PassNevExp = sresult.Properties["PassNevExp"][0].ToString();
                        var DomenskaGrupa = sresult.Properties["DomenskaGrupa"][0].ToString();
                        var Email = sresult.Properties["Email"][0].ToString();

                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["Ime"] = korisnik.Ime;
                        dr["Prezime"] = korisnik.Prezime;
                        dr["LoginName"] = korisnik.LoginName;
                        dr["Status"] = korisnik.Status;
                        dr["AccountExpired"] = korisnik.AccountExpired;
                        dr["PassNevExp"] = korisnik.PassNevExp;
                        dr["DomenskaGrupa"] = korisnik.DomenskaGrupa;
                        dr["Email"] = korisnik.Email;

                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        lstuser.Add(korisnik);

                    }

                }
            }

            return "";
```

}

And in my controller I call `VratiKorisnike()`

```
public IActionResult VratiKorisnike()

    {
        ViewBag.Korisnici = _korisnikServis.VratiKorisnike();            
        return View("Index"); 

}
```

And I use `ViewBag` but there is no data display in `View`

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Korisnici)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Ime</th>
            <th>Prezime</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.Ime</td>
            <td>@Model.Prezime</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: ``VratiKorisnike`` return empty string, should be return ``lstuser`` collection?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AD.Models.DbModels.Korisnik>' to 'string'

Comment: you need to change the declaration also ``public List<Korisnik> VratiKorisnike()`` , but seems the list contains empty object. and after initialization of ``korisnik``, you need to put all variable ``var ..`` into the object ``korisnik``

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to return your `lstuser`, so what you need to do is to change your method's return type to `List<Korisnik>` first and then return the `lstuser` inside your method, so change this:

```
public string VratiKorisnike()
```

To this:

```
public List<Korisnik> VratiKorisnike()
```

And add this:

```
return lstuser;
```

What you need to do secondly, is casting your `ViewBag.Korisnici` to `List<Korisnik>` in your view and use `item` variable instead of `Model` in the foreach loop:

```
    @foreach (var item in (List<Korisnik>)ViewBag.Korisnici)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Ime</th>
            <th>Prezime</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Ime</td>
            <td>@item.Prezime</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```